# SQL Query on MySQL time execution difference

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a question about the execution time of twe very similar queries.

The second query below takes much more time than the first (10 times or more), any clue why? data size?

Thank you in advance.

QUERY 1:

```
SELECT DistinctUUsersID.user_guid AS uUserID, d.user_guid AS dUserID, count(*) AS numrows
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT u.user_guid 
      FROM users u) AS DistinctUUsersID 
LEFT JOIN dogs d
  ON DistinctUUsersID.user_guid=d.user_guid
GROUP BY DistinctUUsersID.user_guid
ORDER BY numrows DESC;
```

QUERY 2:

```
SELECT DistinctUUsersID.user_guid AS uUserID, DistinctDUsersID.user_guid AS dUserID, count(*) AS numrows
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT u.user_guid 
      FROM users u) AS DistinctUUsersID 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT d.user_guid 
      FROM dogs d) AS DistinctDUsersID 
  ON DistinctUUsersID.user_guid=DistinctDUsersID.user_guid
GROUP BY DistinctUUsersID.user_guid
ORDER BY numrows DESC;
```

Comment: you've got a second subquery in the second one, so that's the obvious place to start looking. have you compared the `explain` output of each query?